# Implementing Horner function recursive?

Tags: java, algorithm, recursion

For an exercise I have to implement the Horner function as a recursive method, which is a formula to convert any number system to Decimal, for example for 101101₂, it would be ((((((1·2 + 0)·2) + 1)·2) + 1)·2 + 0)·2 + 1 = 45₁₀

Now the method gets two parameters, an array of digits and the number system, for example 2 for binary.

Now if I were to have a third parameter that would act as a "counter" to go through the array, I'd have no problem but with this I just can't figure it out. I'm allowed to use a helper method, but I tried many different ways and none worked. Maybe I'm thinking more complicated than it actually is. Can someone please give me a tip to lead me in the right direction? ^^

Comment: [Or is it?](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Horner's_method) (a method to evaluate polynomials, that is.)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I thing the following code does what you are asking:

```
public class Main {

    /**
     * Hepler method to convert codepoints ('digitCodePoints') into their decimal corresponding
     * number (to be used with {@link #horner(java.lang.String, java.lang.String) horner method})
     * depending on the alphabet ('alphabetCodePoints').
     * @param digitCodePoints the raw digits of the number (most significant digit first).
     * @param alphabetCodePoints the raw alphabet codepoints of the system (least significant codepoint first). For example "01" for binary.
     * @return 
     */
    private static int[] toDigits(final int[] digitCodePoints,
                                  final int[] alphabetCodePoints) {
        final int[] result = new int[digitCodePoints.length];
        for (int d = 0; d < digitCodePoints.length; ++d) {

            //Find where is the digitCodePoints[d] located in alphabetCodePoints:
            int index = 0;
            while (digitCodePoints[d] != alphabetCodePoints[index]) //Will throw ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException if the digitCodePoints[d] is not found in alphabetCodePoints.
                ++index;

            result[d] = index;
        }
        return result;
    }

    /**
     * Works on codepoints.
     * @param digits the codepoints' literal which stores the digits of the number.
     * @param alphabet the alphabet of the system for which the convertion will take place. For example "01" for binary. Least significant digit comes first.
     * @return the decimal value of the resulting number.
     */
    public static int horner(final String digits,
                             final String alphabet) {
        final int[] alphabetCPs = alphabet.codePoints().toArray();
        return horner(toDigits(digits.codePoints().toArray(), alphabetCPs), alphabetCPs.length);
    }

    public static int horner(final int[] digits,
                             final int system) {
        return horner(digits, 0, digits.length, system);
    }

    /**
     * Standard method for converting 'digits' to their decimal number by Horner's method.
     * @param digits the digits of each place (most significant digit first).
     * @param offset the offset of 'digits' where we should end recursing.
     * @param length the length of 'digits' starting at 'offset'.
     * @param system the system for the convertion. For example 2 for binary, 16 for hexadecimal, and so on.
     * @return the decimal value of the resulting number.
     */
    public static int horner(final int[] digits,
                             final int offset,
                             final int length,
                             final int system) {
        return horner(digits, offset, offset + length - 1, 1, system);
    }

    /**
     * Main recursive method.
     * @param digits the digits of each place (most significant digit first).
     * @param offset the offset of 'digits' where we should end recursing.
     * @param index the index in digits to calculate next.
     * @param step how 'fast' we are traversing the array 'digits'. Typically 1. This exists mainly to create a different method signature than {@link #horner(int[], int, int, int) this} method.
     * @param system the system for the convertion. For example 2 for binary, 16 for hexadecimal, and so on.
     * @return the decimal value of the resulting number.
     */
    private static int horner(final int[] digits,
                              final int offset,
                              final int index,
                              final int step,
                              final int system) {
        if (digits[index] >= system)
            throw new IllegalArgumentException("digits[" + index + "]==" + digits[index] + " does not belong to the system " + system + '.');
        return index - step < offset
               ? digits[index]
               : horner(digits, offset, /* here you can see the usage of 'step': */ index - step, step, system) * system + digits[index];
    }

    public static void main(final String[] args) {
        System.out.println(horner(   new int[]{1, 0, 1, 1}   ,    2   )); //11.
        System.out.println(horner(   new int[]{0xF, 0xF}     ,    16  )); //255.
        System.out.println(horner( /* the number: */ "ffff" , /* the alphabet: */ "0123456789abcdef" )); //65535.
    }
}
```

If you are having trouble understanding what `step` parameter does, consider it being always equal to 1! This is how *fast* the array is traversed. For example a value 2 would mean that only half digits will be taken into consideration. It may complicate things a bit, but I created it to make a different method signature of the main recursive method than the others. You may only use the last *horner* method, by replacing the `step` with 1.

Anyway, I have embedded some javadoc (comments) for every method to help you understand what I am doing. The main implementation is the last *horner* method.

Answer (score 0):

I would do the following where $a is the string containing the number, $b is the system

```
$multiplier = (int)$b;
$result = 0;
while (len($a) > 1) {
  $digit = (int)substr($a, -1);
  $result += $digit * $multiplier;
  $a = substr($a, 0, -1);      
  $multiplier = $multiplier * $b;
}
$result += ((int)$a) * $multiplier;
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer, but the problem is that i need to do it recursive as well as with the array of digits as parameter :/